# Remove 0-byte (UTF-8) characters in String

Tags: java, string, utf-8, network-programming, arrays

I am currently programming a multi-player game, and I am working on the networking side of it all right now. I have a packet system set up, and the way it works (with Strings at least) is that it takes a number of characters to a maximum of "X" characters. The characters are converted to bytes for sending to the server. If there are less than X characters, then the remaining bytes are set to 0. The issue is that when processing this information on the server and converting it to a string, the 0-byte characters are a '□' in my console, and invisible in my JTextPane. How can I remove all of these 0-byte characters from the String in a clean way? I'd prefer not to have another loop and more variables just to remove the 0-bytes before converting to a String. No one likes dirty-looking code. :p

Packet Data:

```
03100101118000000000971001091051100000000
```

- 03 = Packet ID (irrelevant)
- 100101118000000000 = Username ("dev")
- 971001091051100000000 = Password ("admin")

Resulting String:

- usernameString = "dev□□□□□□□□□"
- passwordString = "admin□□□□□□□"

What I've tried:

```
usernameString.replaceAll(new String(new byte[] {0}, "UTF-8"), "");
passwordString.replaceAll(new String(new byte[] {0}, "UTF-8"), "");
```

However, this did not change the String at all.

Comment: use some regex to math end of string being one or more `0`

Comment: If you are using Java 7 or higher, it's better to use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` constant instead of `"UTF-8"` literal. This is faster and you will not need to handle/rethrow `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Comment: @TagirValeev Wow I never realized how much faster `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` was compared to the `"UTF-8"` literal. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As all of your zeros appear at the end of the string you can solve this even without regular expresions:

```
static String trimZeros(String str) {
    int pos = str.indexOf(0);
    return pos == -1 ? str : str.substring(0, pos);
}

usernameString = trimZeros(usernameString);
passwordString = trimZeros(passwordString);
```

Comment: I like this better than a regular expression assuming `0` only occurs at the end.

Comment: @TagirValeev Due to the nature of the packets, there will never be a 0-byte unless it's an unfilled character at the end. It's a great safety-precaution though.

Answer (score 4):

```
usernameString = // replace 1 or more \0 at the end of the string
    usernameString.replaceAll("\0+$", "");
```

`\0` is an escape for the Unicode character with a numerical value 0 (sometimes called NUL). In other words:

```
System.out.println((int) "\0".charAt(0)); // prints 0
```

What you tried seems to work for me too. (See [Ideone example](http://ideone.com/ozaQCc).) Not sure why it doesn't for you. There may be another problem. Make sure you are reassigning the result. ; )

Comment: That does not work for me because there is no '\' before the 0-byte character in the String, nor an actual '0'. The character is essentially null.

Comment: See my edit. Sorry, I suppose I could have explained it initially. `\ ` does not appear in the String, it's an escape.

Comment: This worked fine for me in that case. I chose the other answer as _the_ answer because it looks cleaner, but this code is functional and definitely gets the job done, thanks!